# Automating doctest?

Tags: python, doctest

If I were to automate `doctest.testmod()` how would this occur? It appears `testmod` runs the tests over the module and provided a string result `TestResults`. Unsure how to parse this.

```
def average(values):
    """Computes the arithmetic mean of a list of numbers.
    >>> print(average([20, 30, 70])) 
    40.0
    """
    return sum(values) / len(values)

import doctest
r = doctest.testmod()
print(r)

# TestResults(failed=0, attempted=1)
```

Comment: Parse it _to what end_? Typically you just put the import and test behind `if __name__ == "__main__":` then you can import the functionality you want from that file, or execute it directly to test it. What are you trying to _do_ with the result?

Comment: I thought the returned value would be a list or tuple?  I think in it's current form I need to parse for attempted with a regex?

Comment: A list or tuple _of what_? And why would you need to parse anything - it's a simple object, `r.attempted` would be the value `1`. Again, _to what end_ are you trying to use this object?